# Need for a temporary variable

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, just started a couple of days ago, from scratch. I tried a Matrix program to understand the functioning of the "for" loop,using Eclipse IDE.

> ```
> package day1.examples;
>
> public class MatrixClass {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>       int[][] a = new int[4][3];
>
>       int temp=15;
>       int i = 0;
>       int j = 0;
>       a[i][j]=0;
>       for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>           System.out.println();
>           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
>               a[i][j]=temp;
>               temp = temp + 15;
>               System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
>
>           }
>
>       }
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Output:

```
15 30 45 
60 75 90 
105 120 135 
150 165 180
```

The above program works well and I get the desired output. What I do not understand is the need for a temporary variable. Why isn't it possible to use the existing variable itself,for increment? 
When I try increasing the existing variable (a[i][j]),why is there no increment in the value in the output,even though the code gets executed?

```
package day1.examples;

public class MatrixClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[][] a = new int[4][3];

        //int temp=15;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        a[i][j]=0;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //a[i][j]=temp;
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] + 15;
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
15 15 15 
15 15 15 
15 15 15 
15 15 15
```

Comment: One thing that often helps if you have a hard time following the values of variables is to take pen and paper and have the current variable values written down, and then update them while going through the lines of code one by one. It's not very fast but helps especially when you've just started writing Java.

Comment: thanks MJV. that is indeed,helpful.

Comment: Oh, and since you're using Eclipse, it's very easy (and more reliable than the pen and paper approach) to use its debugger for this.

Comment: @MJV not sure how to use that,but I will eventually learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are initialized by default to their default values. Read this:

- [Oracle tutorial on Default values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Therefore, when you add 15 to each cell, you have `a[i][j] = 0 + 15;`

---

What you've called a temporary variable has the language buzzword [accumulator (definition #7)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accumulator).

> A register in a calculator or computer used for holding the intermediate results of a computation or data transfer.

This value changes each time you go through the loop, which is why the values come out different. If you don't use a temporary variable, you would have to compute the results from the values of `i` and `j` every time (in this case, using a formula like `(i * 3 + j) * 15`)

Comment: ok,this is EXACTLY what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot. Best answer. Apparently,I need "reputation" to vote it up, sorry.

Comment: I have another question. You said "Arrays are initialized by default to their default values." I have now set the default value (a[i][j]=15;) in place where it was "=0" earlier. Now the output is like :
30 15 15 
15 15 15 
15 15 15 
15 15 15 

Shouldn't all the elements be 30 now? Because it has to re-initialize to the default value,which is 15. But it becomes zero instead.

Comment: Since setting the starting value isn't inside the loop in your code, when you write `int i=0; int j=0; a[i][j]=15;` you're really doing only `a[0][0] = 15;`, i.e. only the very first element in your matrix is set. All the other positions (`a[0][1]` etc.) are left to their Java-specific default values (which is 0 for `int`).

Comment: Uhh..I got it. I feel so dumb. Understood now. What I mentioned is the "initial value". What you guys are talking about is the "default value". Sigh! Sorry. :)
and also understood your explanation,MJV. thanks. :)

Comment: Exactly. I had trouble of thinking the right word to use when talking about the value that you were setting yourself. "Initial value" is much better than the "starting value" I used but the main point is the difference between that and the default value that Java in itself sets to the variables. :)

Comment: @durron597 True, I guess my comment didn't really add anything to that.

Comment: @durron597 after reading the tutorial is when I realized how dumb my second question was :D

Answer (score 2):

Your `a[i][j] = a[i][j] + 15;` line inside the last of your examples takes the `a[i][j]` value, and increases it by 15. You have nowhere in your code initialized values of your matrix, so all values are 0.

When you understand that `a[i][j]` points to a new variable every time `i` or `j` changes, you will understand everything.

This means all values in the matrix are 15.

I'd make the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        a[i][j-1] = 15 * (j + (i * 3))
        System.out.println(a[i][j-1] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I saw this at the same time you did, it is fixed now

Comment: thank you. I just needed an explanation of temp,though. Anyway,how does a[i][j] = (i * 15) + (j * 15) differ from my use of temp?

Comment: It does not differ from your use of `temp` in any other way than that I think it's easier to understand

Comment: Thanks Anton[H], assumed it was 4x4 matrix. thanks. Downvote serves no purpose here though.

Comment: Your array values are not correct. Just look at first iteration, `i=1` and `j=1`, it gives `30` where `15` is expected.

Comment: Sigh, yeah. Should be ok now x) - you know, its so wrong . wow

Comment: I think this should be the proper solution

Comment: @hewo Almost there. You should, when initialising the value of the array, use `a[i][j-1]` (otherwise you go OutOfBoundaries on first iteration) and, in the `println`, use `a[i][j-1]`. When that's corrected I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Sorry I had to take care of some issues. Thanks for fixing the coherency :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you declare a temp variable as 15 and increase its value by 15 each time you store it in array, Whereas in the second case you are taking value of a[i][j] and since a[i][j] is only initialized for a[0][0] and not for others , so according to the language standard it automatically gets initialized to the arrays primitve type , which in this case is int and for int the default is zero. Hence each time only 0+15 i.e 15 is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that `temp` is not cleared when moving to the next element, which allows it to accumulate the value from all the cells. If you wanted to do this without a temporary variable, you would need to somehow copy the value from one element to the next before adding 15.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is what I actually needed to know: Any reason why temp does not clear itself but a[i][j] is cleared eventhough the initialization to zero is outside the for loop?
edit: nevermind. understood from the other comments. :)